# UIRefreshControl not spinning when beginRefreshing is called from delegate

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, uirefreshcontrol

I have a main view controller with this fonction

```
  func beginQueryData()
  {
    if !refreshControl.refreshing {
      refreshControl.beginRefreshing()
      if let colView = collectionView {
        colView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: colView.contentOffset.y - refreshControl.frame.height), animated: true)
      }
    queryData()
    }
  }
```

This works fine when called in viewDidAppear of viewDidLoad.

Now, I have a setting view controller that I push on top of this view controller.
Each time I change a setting in the setting view controller, I call the beginQueryData() of my viewController that is set as a delegate of the setting view controller. (**delegate.settingsChanged()**)

The problem:

the main viewController is refreshed, the spinning icon is shown but it's not animating...
I tried to endRefreshing and beginRefreshing in viewDidLoad() but it doesn't work, the spinning icon just disappears.

Comment: Please check current thread, you should call method on main thread

Comment: I'm on the main thread. I just found a way to fix the problem. But it doesn't really explain why it's not spinning in the previous case. In my fix, I call the delegate only when I dismiss the settings view controller, in viewWillDisappear. Now, it's animated... when trying to call the delegate when the user interact with the settings UI (ex: change switches, changes options..) the refreshControl change of state just doesn't work.

Comment: You must provide more code..

Comment: It's a simple UICollectionViewController with a UIRefreshControl. nothing more.

Comment: Are you running refreshControl.beginRefreshing() when you application in background? You can not work with UI in background

Comment: No, not in background. It's just a view that I pushed that is asking the caller view to refresh. It's really weird, the refresh is working, it's just the spin animation that is stuck...

Comment: I know this is ancient history, but I have just encountered this problem also.  In my case, my view structure includes a slideout settings menu, which it sounds like you may have also had.  My settings view was not involved at all (other than existing), but I found deleting it would fix the animation problem.  I'm wondering if some kind of parent/child viewController problem triggers this.